# Repeat Keys settings don't work after reboot in Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard, accessibility

I'm not even sure where to start diagnosing this problem, and I'm looking for help.

In Settings > Universal Access, in the "Typing" section I have "Repeat Keys" turned on.

The problem is that if I reboot those settings don't work.

If I got back into the settings, it shows the option as enabled.

Turning it off and back on again fixes the problem, but it's annoying to do that after every reboot.

This is on 20.04.01 LTS.

Comment: It's a bug - and I can confirm it happens on unplugging/replugging the kb. See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1466 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1899206

Answer (score -1):

You have to press 'save settings' or go into the UEFI settings and turn it on there the go > exit > save changes > or exit and save changes. You can go there pressing F12.

Comment: Thanks - but there's no "Save settings" on that screen. With UEFI, are you referring to the BIOS? There's no setting for that in Ubuntu 20.04, either.

Comment: Yeah, i am referring to BIOS

Comment: The question is about Gnome. An answer about BIOS which loads before grub which loads before systemd which loads before Gnome is not helpful.